# Font text boundary larger than text content

Tags: css, fonts

Highlighted in red is the boundary of the `BrownProBold-Regular` font on our site, without any explicit height, padding, or line-height. You can see there's a few pixels of extra spacing underneath the text which is making it difficult to align the stars with the text. On iOS (both Chrome and Safari) this red border is collapsed around the content and does not include that extra space.

[image]

How would one solve for this? I tried setting explicit heights and line-heights for the element but that still produced an inconsistent sizing. Others have suggested applying `text-size-adjust: 100%;` but that made no difference.

Comment: Without seeing your code, my first guess would be this is a "line-height" issue. Try adjusting that and see if it goes away on non-iOS devices.

Comment: Nope - setting line-height didn't create consistency. Also checked if there was any custom zooming on devices.